# Translating 3D CNN from Keras to Pytorch

Tags: keras, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to translate the below 3D CNN architecture from keras to pytorch. The 3D images all have the following dimensions: 193 x 229 x 193.

Network architecture in Keras:

```
def test_model(size):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv3D(filters=8,
                     kernel_size=(3, 3, 3),
                     activation='relu',
                     input_shape=size,
                     name="conv_1_1"))
    model.add(Conv3D(filters=8,
                     kernel_size=(3, 3, 3),
                     activation='relu',
                     name="conv_1_2"))
    model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2),
                           strides=(2, 2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv3D(filters=16,
                     kernel_size=(3, 3, 3),
                     activation='relu',
                     input_shape=size,
                     name="conv_2_1"))
    model.add(Conv3D(filters=16,
                     kernel_size=(3, 3, 3),
                     activation='relu',
                     name="conv_2_2"))
    model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2),
                           strides=(2, 2, 2)))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(units=1,
                    name="d_2"))
    return model
```

My attempt at translating this to Pytorch:

```
class Model(torch.nn.Module): 
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv3d(input_channel=1, output_channel=8, kernel_size=3)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv3d(input_channel=8, output_channel=8, kernel_size=3)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv3d(input_channel=8, output_channel=16, kernel_size=3)
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv3d(input_channel=16, output_channel=16, kernel_size=3)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear( ???? , 1)

     def forward (self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = F.relu(F.max_pool3d(self.conv2(x), kernel_size=2, stride=2))
        x = F.relu(self.conv3(x))
        x = F.relu(F.max_pool3d(self.conv4(x), kernel_size=2, stride=2))
        x = self.fc1

        return x
    
net = Model()
```

Please could you let me know where I've made mistakes and also clarify how to determine the input for the nn.Linear( ???? , 2) layer? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspecting your last [`nn.Conv3d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv3d.html)'s output, you have a tensor shape of `(-1, 16, 45, 54, 45)`. Therefore, you need a total of `16*45*54*45=1749600` connections on your dense layer (**this is tremendously large!**).

Some other things to point out:

- `input_channel` and `output_channels` should be `in_channels` and `out_channels`, respectively.
- You can either use `torch.flatten(x, start_dim=1)` or a [`nn.Flatten()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Flatten.html) layer (which will flatten from `axis=1` to `axis=-1` by default).
- you have misplaced an `F.relu` activation as your overall structure is `[conv3d, relu, conv3d, relu, maxpool3d] + [conv3d, relu, conv3d, relu, maxpool3d] + [flatten, dense]`.

---

Resulting code:

```
class Model(torch.nn.Module): 
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv3d(in_channels=1, out_channels=8, kernel_size=3)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv3d(in_channels=8, out_channels=8, kernel_size=3)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv3d(in_channels=8, out_channels=16, kernel_size=3)
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv3d(in_channels=16, out_channels=16, kernel_size=3)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1749600, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = F.max_pool3d(x, kernel_size=2, stride=2)

        x = F.relu(self.conv3(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv4(x))
        x = F.max_pool3d(x, kernel_size=2, stride=2)

        x = torch.flatten(x, start_dim=1)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        return x
```

Comment: Thanks @Ivan, this is really helpful. Could I just ask how you computed the tensor shape of (-1, 16, 45, 54, 45) and also what the -1 refers to?

Comment: Sure, I guess you could compute the output shape layer by layer looking at the formula [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv3d.html). However this easiest is to truncate your model (remove the `torch.flatten` and `fc1` calls in forward and look at the shape of the output. Don't worry about the `-1`, it refers to the batch size, I could have just put `B` or `batch_size` there!